# What is a residual ring?

Tags: c++, arrays, ring

So I have this task (Define a C ++ function that fills an array with the elements of the residual Zn ring.) and I can't understand the meaning of the residual ring?

Comment: [Quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) - Since this is not a question about programming, perhaps it'd be better to ask about this at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171377/what-does-quotient-ring-mean)?

Comment: Yes, I know that it is connected with mathematics  but the question is how can I write it in a code?

Comment: Your question is "_What is a residual ring?_" so I suggest that you start by figuring that out and then _try_ to implement this function. If you fail implementing it, then ask here at SO and be sure to include the code you've got so far.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!